# WinUI 3 - loading image fails

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3

**Conclusion:**
I tried to modify the application according to all the advice - avoiding loading from the stream, using ObservableProperty, using RelayCommand, and the error still persists. However, only in my virtualized DEV environment and on one of the customer's two computers. I have come to the conclusion that the issue lies in the environment, not in the application itself. Thank you for your support.

---

I'm developing an application in WinUI 3, and I'm experiencing random failures when loading an image from disk into the Image element. There is a binding between the Source property of the Image element and the ViewModel.

```xml
<Image Source="{Binding MainImageSource}" />
```

```cs
private BitmapImage mainImageSource = null;
public BitmapImage MainImageSource
{
    get => mainImageSource;
    set
    {
        mainImageSource = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainImageSource));
    }
}
```

```cs
MainImageSource = await GetImageSourceFromAssets("quiz_intro_main.png");
```

```cs
private static async Task<BitmapImage> GetImageSourceFromAssets(string path)
{
    StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, $"Assets\\{path}"));
    using IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new();
    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);

    return bitmapImage;
}
```

If I repeatedly set the MainImageSource property, the image randomly fails to display, and a white screen remains.

I have created a [proof of concept](https://github.com/usdarmy/set-image-source-fail-poc) where the described behavior can be reproduced. Clicking within the application loads another image. If I click repeatedly (sometimes even longer than a minute, patience is required), the image fails to load. In the debugger, the loading looks okay, and the Live Property Explorer shows everything as if it were loaded correctly.

If the above-mentioned code is part of a more complex application (with multiple pages and navigation between them), the error occurs earlier.

The error occurs in my development environment with Windows 10, as well as at the customer's site with Windows 11.

I have tried other methods of loading the image, changing the binding, caching the BitmapImage, and none of them helped.

Comment: Your code seems correct, and I don't reproduce any problem with it. I've tried a 1ms timer to automate the switch instead of furiously clicking and it works fine too, also tried with a cache (Windows 11, Windows 10 in hyper-v) are you sure it's not caused by video driver or disk issues

Comment: @SimonMourier, with a 1ms timer, are you sure you'll notice that the image didn't display once? The app doesn't crash, it just doesn't display the image, it continues to respond normally and displays the next image when clicked. For me the error manifests itself after about a minute and a half of intense clicking. Once the first time the image doesn't display, the error starts to show up more often. Maybe every fifth view. My development environment runs on Windows 10 virtualized in VMware Fusion. I'm going to try to focus on the video card driver.

Comment: I've tried everything not only the timer, w/o any error and your code is ok anyway. Here is a video https://1drv.ms/v/s!AsmmEDGvydk2v0raeFw7LeAHeI3D?e=3XHpVA (can't stand too much!) might want to have a look at GPU driver settings such as vsync, freesync, gsync, any super advanced features, etc.

Answer (score 0):

why you are using BitmapImage?
change BitmapImage to string:

```
private string mainImageSource = null;
public string MainImageSource
{
    get => mainImageSource;
    set
    {
        mainImageSource = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainImageSource));
    }
}
```

and in your switch statement change to this:

```
case State.Intro:
    var sourceUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/quiz_intro_main.png");
    MainImageSource = sourceUri.AbsolutePath;
    break;
case State.Conditions:
    var sourceUri2 = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/quiz_conditions_main.png");
    MainImageSource = sourceUri2.AbsolutePath;
    break;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Katana, for the tip. I adjusted the code according to your example, and the error persists. After some time, the image simply does not display. Additionally, when swapping the image, there's an unpleasant white flash. By the way, I thought that this method of setting the Source couldn't be used in an unpacked application.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code? Might improve and speed up your image switching process.

First of all, you need to install these NuGet packages:

- **CommunityToolkit.Mvvm**:
  It comes with source generators that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` for you.
- **Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.WinUI.Managed**:
  We can use this to connect UI events to ViewModel commands.

**ImageViewModel.cs**

```cs
// This class needs to be "partial".
public partial class ImageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    // This auto-generates a "State" property.
    private State _state;

    [ObservableProperty]
    // This auto-generates a "MainImageSource" property.
    private string _mainImageSource = string.Empty;

    private readonly Dictionary<State, string> _imageSources = new()
    {
        { State.Intro, "/Assets/quiz_intro_main.png" },
        { State.Conditions, "/Assets/quiz_conditions_main.png" },
    };

    public ImageViewModel()
    {
        State = State.Intro;
    }

    partial void OnStateChanged(State value)
    {
        if (_imageSources.TryGetValue(value, out string source) is false)
        {
            return;
        }

        MainImageSource = source;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    // This auto-generates a "SwapStateCommand".
    private void SwapState()
    {
        State = State switch
        {
            State.Intro => State.Conditions,
            State.Conditions => State.Intro,
            _ => State.None,
        };
    }
}
```

**ImagePage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class ImagePage : Page
{
    public ImagePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private ImageViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}
```

**ImagePage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="App6.ImagePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerPressed">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SwapStateCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <Canvas
        Width="1920"
        Height="1080">
        <Image Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.MainImageSource, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Canvas>
</Page>
```

Comment: The bug no longer seems to be manifesting itself. There is just an annoying flash of white. I'm using ObservableObject in the original application, so the only difference is the use of RelayCommand. Is it possible that my original PointerPressed handler is running in a different thread than RelayCommand? That would also explain the randomness of the error. In the next step, I will try the original image loading from the code (without white flickering when changing images) along with RealCommand as an event handler.

Comment: When I started rewriting the original application according to your recommendation, the error started manifesting again. I have come to the conclusion that the issue lies in the environment, as I mentioned in the conclusion of the original question.